# How to create nuget package for xamarin.ios

Tags: xamarin.ios, nuget

I have created a Xamarin.iOS UI component without core project, only a Xamarin.iOS project, and I would like to package it with nuget which I can use across several projects. But I can't handle it.

I'm looking for proper steps for creating a Nuget Package based on my Xamarin solution.

The only thing I found is this command line `nuget pack your.nuspec`.

Obviously I'm on mac.

Thank's

Anthony;

Comment: Clearly you know the answer already. Why cannot you use `nuget pack` that way?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to make a nuget for ios - Visual studio for Mac.

Open project settings in ios settings page and enable "create package when building the project".[image]

Then go to the Metadata and fill it. After that choose release mode and build, and finally check output directory(yourprojectname/bin/release).

Comment: To make thanks, you can mark this as answer @AnthonyNfr